# Configuration File on Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, configuration-files

I'm new programming with Objective-C (my strongest skills is .Net), on .Net there's a configuration file that the user can modified and the app gets this modified values.
My question is: There's something similar on Objective- C (my app is for Mac OS X)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about preferences, that's handled by the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. The standard location for preferences to be written is ~/Library/Preferences/bundleidentifier.plist (where bundleidentifier is your bundle's identifier — e.g., com.apple.preview for Apple's Preview app). You can technically write plists anywhere, but it's bad form to go scribbling outside the standard locations without the user's say-so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes.. I'm looking something like this, that the user can, for example, change the server's IP address